# Trouble Getting VirtualEnvWrapper working on Cygwin

Tags: windows, python-3.x, cygwin, virtualenvwrapper

I'm running Windows 10, Python 3.4 and just installed Cygwin.  I installed `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper` using `pip`.  I updated my ~/.bashrc to have the following:

```
export WORKON_HOME=~/.virtualenvs
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=c:/python35/scripts/virtualenv
source c:/python35/scripts/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

But unfortunately, I keep getting an error message very time I open Cygwin. The following error comes up:

```
path = C:\Cygwin64\tmp/virtualenvwrapper-initialize-hook-XXXXXXXXXX
lpPathBuffer = C:\Cygwin64\tmp\
szTempName = C:\Cygwin64\tmp\tmp66C6.tmp
path = C:\Cygwin64\tmp\tmp66C6.tmp
fd = 3
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating C:\home\ccordero\.virtualenvs\initialize
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating C:\home\ccordero\.virtualenvs\premkproject
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python35\lib\runpy.py", line 184, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\virtualenvwrapper\hook_loader.py", line 223, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\virtualenvwrapper\hook_loader.py", line 138, in main
    output = open(options.script_filename, "w")
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\\Cygwin64\\tmp/virtualenvwrapper-initialize-hook-XXXXXXXXXX\r'
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.
```

Please help!

Comment: Have you tried providing a Cygwin-type directory in `export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=$(cygpath -u c:/python35/scripts/virtualenv)`? Also, why not use venv that comes with Python 3? https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/venv.html